# Checkbox inside ion-slides with loop enabled

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides, ion-checkbox

I have a page which contains ion-slides with loop enabled. Each slide is generated with *ngFor and each one contains a checkbox. The problem I am facing is that the checkbox is not getting checked on first and last slides. I have found that its because there are duplicate slides for the first slide and last slide so clicking on the checkbox is not triggering it since there are duplicates for the same. I have tried giving Id to checkbox to make it unique but since the slides are generated dynamically whatever change I give is also getting replicated. Is there any workaround for this? Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Here is my code

*HTML part*

```
<ion-slides pager='true' loop="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of demoData">
        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>{{slide}}</ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

*Ts Part*

```
demoData = ['1', '2', '3'];
```

Comment: sounds you should be checking how you are getting _ there are duplicate slides for the first slide and last slide_? Not sure what you mean by this

Comment: I am new to ionic so I don't know exactly what happens in the background but when loop is set to true ionic will create a duplicate slides for the first slide and the last slide.

Comment: can you add the ts part of this?

Comment: Do you need the whole ts file ?

Comment: the _relevant code_.. see [mcve]

Comment: I have edited the code. Can you please check now. If you still need any more info please ask away